# MySQL: SUM function applied to a formula contained in field selected by another query

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm in the need to perform a select SUM() where that  is a formula contained into a field selected by another query.
Example:

table_A (the "formula" field contains, in each cell, an arithmetic expression involving columns from table B):

```
+------------+--------------+------------+
| Product_id | related_prod |  formula   |
+------------+--------------+------------+
| U1         | C2           | col2-col1  |
| U2         | C3           | col3-col2  |
| U3         | C4           | col3-col1  |
+------------+--------------+------------+
```

table_B:

```
+------------+---------+------------+----------+------+------+------+
| Product_id | year_id | company_id | month_id | col1 | col2 | col3 |
+------------+---------+------------+----------+------+------+------+
| C2         |    2017 |          1 |        2 |  100 |  200 |  300 |
| C3         |    2017 |          1 |        2 |  400 |  500 |  600 |
| C4         |    2017 |          1 |        2 |  700 |  800 |  900 |
+------------+---------+------------+----------+------+------+------+
```

I do, then, the following query:

```
SELECT 
SUM(totals.relaz) as final_sum, 
totals.relaz as 'col', 
totals.prod as 'prod', 
totals.cons as 'cons', 
m.company_id, m.month_id, m.year_id, FROM `table_B` m, 
    ( SELECT formula as relaz, 
     related_prod as prod,
     p.product_id as cons FROM table_A p  ) 
     AS totals 
WHERE m.product_id=totals.prod 
GROUP BY m.company_id, m.year_id, m.month_id, m.product_id, totals.cons
```

After the select I'd do expect that, considering for example the only product 'U1', the corresponding row would be

```
+-----------+-----------+------+------+------------+----------+---------+
| final_sum |    col    | prod | cons | company_id | month_id | year_id |
+-----------+-----------+------+------+------------+----------+---------+
|       100 | col2-col1 | C2   | U1   |          1 |        2 |    2017 |
+-----------+-----------+------+------+------------+----------+---------+
```

Instead, what I get is

```
+-----------+-----------+------+------+------------+----------+---------+
| final_sum |    col    | prod | cons | company_id | month_id | year_id |
+-----------+-----------+------+------+------------+----------+---------+
|         0 | col2-col1 | C2   | U1   |          1 |        2 |    2017 |
+-----------+-----------+------+------+------------+----------+---------+
```

i.e. the final_sum field is always set to 0, despite the 'col' field contains the correct equation.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance
Alex

Comment: This kind of problem is (as I think you have guessed) symptomatic of poor design.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get sum from a string column (table_A.formula). This will result 0. MySQL/MariaDB will not try to convert the strings to column references and evaluate the formula in the string.

Another thing is that you should list all columns not in aggregate function in GROUP BY.

To get the result you want, use:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(CASE 
      WHEN a.formula = 'col2-col1' THEN b.col2-b.col1 
      WHEN a.formula = 'col3-col1' THEN b.col3-b.col1 
      WHEN a.formula = 'col3-col2' THEN b.col3-b.col2
     END
     ) AS final_sum, 
  a.formula as 'col', 
  a.related_prod as 'prod', 
  a.Product_id as 'cons', 
  b.company_id, 
  b.month_id, 
  b.year_id
FROM table_B b
  JOIN table_A a on a.related_prod=b.Product_id 
GROUP BY a.formula, a.related_prod, a.Product_id, b.company_id, b.month_id, b.year_id
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer.
I was wondering about something like this...
The problem is that the formula field's content may continuously change, so that it's impossible to wrap it inside a SUM(CASE()).

So... there isn't any way to pass such value to the SUM function without MySQL to interpolate it?

Comment: That would require application level logic parsing the columns from the text and evaluating the formula. SQL is not meant to be used like that. How many combinations can you have. Do you have more that 3 data columns, if so, you might want to reconsider the database structure.

Comment: Application is already doing this. I was trying to find a way to perform everything through SQL.

Comment: In other languages there is an `eval()` function.  SQL has no such.

Answer (score 0):

It *may* possible to build a Stored routine that fetches the string `col2-col1` and inserts it (using `CONCAT`) into a string, then `PREPAREs` and `EXECUTEs` the SQL string.

That is, dynamically build the SQL, perhaps like in @slaakso's Answer.

It would be messy.

I have needed something like this; I chose to do `eval()` in PHP, which was the client language.  I use it for evaluating `VARIABLES` and `GLOBAL STATUS`.  Example: `Table_open_cache_misses / Uptime` gives the "misses per second", which, if high, indicates the need for increasing the setting `table_open_cache`.